# Why does the first iteration of this not wait for user input from STDIN?

Tags: ruby, iteration, stdin

I'm finding this a bit odd.  I would expect each iteration of `parse_line(ARGF.read_line)` here to wait for input from STDIN.  What actually is happening is the first iteration skips waiting for user input, but subsequent iterations do wait.  My temporary workaround is just to iterate an extra time.

```
def parse_line(line)
  line.split(" ").map(&:to_i)
end

def get_number_of_slices
  parse_line(ARGF.readline(1)).first
end

def get_all_slice_dimensions(number_of_slices)
  number_of_slices += 1 # for some reason the first read doesn't wait for user input...
  number_of_slices.times.collect { puts "iter"; parse_line(ARGF.readline) }
end

def main
  puts (get_all_slice_dimensions get_number_of_slices)
end

main
```

*Added code so that it is a full working program. I found that when I changed `readline(1)` to `readline` in `get_number_of_slices`, I did not need to add 1 to `number_of_slices` in `get_all_slice_dimensions` any longer, but I would still like to know the reason why this affects the behavior. If you pay attention to the output, iter will print twice the first time.*

Comment: That ruby code doesn't run; it will help us if you can edit it so it runs.

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson: This code runs, now.  I added the implementations for `get_number_of_slices` and `parse_line`.  It seems that calling `readchar(1)` before `readline` was causing the first call to readline to skip waiting for using input.  I'm still curious about the reason for this.

Comment: Sorry `readchar(1)` doesn't make sense, it should be `readline(1)`.  this has been corrected above.

Comment: Can you simplify your post, so it's your specific current question, and code that does what you're describing as the skip?

Comment: This code DOES do what I'm describing.  run it.  I tested it out myself after correcting the readchar(1) bug.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding what ARGF.readline(1) does. It reads one character from the concatenation of each of the named files in the ARGF array. Whereas your description sounds like you're trying to read a line from STDIN, which means you should replace ARGF with STDIN, and ARGF.readline(1) with STDIN.readline (or the `gets` method)